# Multiple background images not showing

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a web page with multiple images but for some reason only one of them loads.

Here is the relevant part of the css:

```
#Upper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url('Imgs/006-Code Geass.jpg');
    background-color: #ff6a00;
}

#Lower {  
    width: 100%;
    height: 18%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#lft {
    width: 33%;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    background-image: url('Imgs/Camera.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#cnt {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#rtg {
    width: 33%;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

#Footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2%;
    background-color: #ff6a00;
}
```

and here is the html:

```
<body>

    <div id="Upper">
        Trying to see you my friend
        <div>
            Cominudapp una red social hecha al tamaño de tu ciudad

        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="Lower">

        <div id="lft">
            Inscribir camara
        </div>

        <div id="cnt">
            Mapa de criminalidad
        </div>

        <div id="rtg">
            Comunidades seguras
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="Footer">
        Hello World
    </div>

</body>
```

Both images are in the same folder but only the Code Geass one will show. The images are in no way final and will be changed as soon as the real ones arrive but we are required to show this working .

Edit:

Changed height to 100% and it still failed. Shut down the computer for the break and it was working properly when it turned on. I don't know how or why so I'm letting the question open.

Comment: Are you sure the image is in the correct folder and named correctly? Check your developer console to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Personally I'd avoid spaces in file names like `006-Code Geass.jpg`

Comment: I know but it was the only image we had about the same and curiously the one that is working properly.

Comment: I'm guessing you've referenced an image incorrectly because your CSS is okay. Here's a jsFiddle that demonstrates it working with some random images from the web: http://jsfiddle.net/jetweedy/3tom49kt/1/ - like APAD1 said, double-check your folders/names, and see if the dev console (F12 > Network tab) suggests that anything is missing.

Comment: Firefox doesn't show any problem. Chrome gives me this: extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in event handler for extension.onRequest: chrome.extension.onRequest content.js has wrong request.name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picture are actually in write position.
The problem in your html tag
you have not specify any fixed width and just use '%' so here the background size is the size of text area.

You can check it as:

```
  <div id="lft">
    Inscribir camara<br>
    some text</br><br>
    some more text</br><br>
    more text</br>
 </div>
```